# How to add "Sign In with Apple" functionality in iOS using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer, apple-developer-account, apple-developer-enterprise

I have Apple's enterprise account. I wanted to add "Sign In with Apple" capability for my, but there's no option to add that capability from apple developer console. I cannot add that capability neither from Xcode nor Apple's certificate generate page, because there's no option of "Sign In with Apple".
I'm running on Xcode 11. When I try to add that capability from Xcode, it throws following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QU20.png)

I'm not sure if it is happening due to enterprise account, because this does not happen in personal accounts.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign In with Apple is not available for Enterprise Apps.

https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6